# React Native stuck on splash screen

Tags: android, react-native, expo

The React Native app is stuck on the splash screen after removing the **expo-splash-screen** package on **android**. It is stuck even after installing the package again. The build is successful but the app not loading the initial screen.
I'm using React Native **bare-workflow**.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.4",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.0.3",
    "expo-av": "^9.1.2",
    "expo-constants": "^10.1.3",
    "expo-font": "^9.1.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "^10.1.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.10.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.5.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "^9.1.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.44.3",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.7",
    "react-native-ffmpeg": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^7.3.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.13.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0"
  },
```

Comment: please check your console, there must be an error displayed. You removed a package that is being used in the application. you must remove splash screen code as well. This way there will be no splash screen and the application will work.

Comment: No there is no error displayed in the console. That's why I'm unable to debug.

Comment: Did you tried removing `expo-splash-screen` imports and its corresponding code?

Comment: There is no import of expo-splash screen in any component. However the expo-splash-screen is showing in console while running the command npx react-native run-android like: **> Configure project :app
Installing unimodules: expo-splash-screen@0.11.2**

Comment: if it's showing the splash screen then it is not completely removed from the project. Sometimes my app also gets stuck on the splash screen but it shows an error in the console. It might have something to do with the expo, I don't have any experience working with the expo.

Comment: Also when I revert back to the previous commit where everything was working fine, it is now giving the error **Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider**.

Comment: This is an issue within react native. Its resolved by closing the app and reopening it. Also, it shows some other error(u have to resolve) in the console before showing `Invariant Violation: Tried to register...` several times.

Comment: I tried what you said. But it still not working. The console output is: **LOG      Running "main" with {"rootTag":1}
ERROR    Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider
 ERROR    Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.**